# How can I remove white pages in FPDF in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysqli, fpdf

[image: How can i remove white page? Data is not showing in front of their specific column.I have used multi cell option but when it display the data in specific width its crosses(X) is displaying in bottom of the page instead of displaying in front of the name.I have to remove these white spaces and displaying the data in a one grid.This issue is repeated many times and I was stuck in it.]

How can i remove white page? Data is not showing in front of their specific column.I have used multi cell option but when it display the data in specific width its crosses(X) is displaying in bottom of the page instead of displaying in front of the name.I have to remove these white spaces and displaying the data in a one grid.This issue is repeated many times and i was stuck in it.

Answer (score 0):

MulitCell in fpdf does not have good support to go across a page.
If it's possible for you, the simplest solution is to use Cell instead of mulitCell, or to limit the number of rows in multiCell to prevent it from going to the next page. However, if you use a Cell, you will need to limit the length of the data so that it doesn't extend past the boundaries of the cell.

Comment: when i use cell it doesn't wrap the text in a specified width and its overlapping to the text of the next cell.But when i use multi cell it wrap the text in a specified width but issue remains the same as the above image in the question,

Comment: See my edit. If you are not able to shorten the data that you want to display, you will need to do a significant amount of labor to make multiCell work for you.